# How to Pull Google Sheet API After Z Column?

Tags: php, google-sheets

With some references: [Srijan](https://www.srijan.net/blog/integrating-google-sheets-with-php-is-this-easy-know-how) and [Google](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php), I managed to pull Google Sheet content from multiple tabs, however, I have some tabs with more than 26 columns, with the current API I could only get until the Z column. Is there any workaround for this? I have more columns from AZ til BZ.

[Google Sheet Screenshot Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYHcd.png)

So if I didn't check with isset, it will hit an error when it starting to read after Z column, which is the AA column. See this:
[Offset error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewbVx.png)

Comment: Google Sheets supports to use ranges like `A1:BF21`. Could you add a minimal snippet of code so we can see if there is some kind of typo? (do not add all the code, only the part that you get the data)

Comment: @Martí you are right, I didn't realize I actually set the range until Z. what a stupid mistake. thank you so much for getting me to look through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving this as an answer to give more visibility to the solution.

Google Sheets uses A1 notation for  defining ranges ([see documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation)). When querying data using the API you use the same notation. Because of that, you may define ranges like `A1:BK21`.

In this case OP was requesting a range that ended at `Z` instead of `BZ`. Note that sometimes you don’t know how many rows or columns you may have. In those cases you may use an open ended range to select all the available:

- For rows: `A1:BK`
- For columns: `A1:21`